# How can I improve this component or separate it into shorter ones?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and the only way I got this to work was like this. But it seems absurdly big compared to other components I have.

What I have here is basically 4 Selects, each depending on the previous one, showing information from a single JSON that I fetch.

Example:
I need to know which `game` is selected to then show the `list of model types` available for this game, to then show a `list of available models of this type`, etc.

I've tried `useContext` and `props` with no success

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
// JUST LAYOUT RELATED STUFF
import Container from '../components/layout/Container';
import Logo from '../components/layout/Logo';
import VerticalAd1 from '../components/modelviewerpage/VerticalAd1';

export default function ModelViewerPage() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [gameListData, setGameListData] = useState({});
  const [selectedGame, setSelectedGame] = useState(null);
  const [selectedType, setSelectedType] = useState(null);
  const [selectedModel, setSelectedModel] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      'https://static.teemo.gg/teemo/sites/main/js/skins-list.json',
    ).then((response) => response.json()).then((data) => {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setGameListData(data);
    });
  }, []);

  const gameSelectInput = document.getElementById('game-select');
  const typeSelectInput = document.getElementById('type-select');
  const modelSelectInput = document.getElementById('model-select');
  const skinSelectInput = document.getElementById('skin-select');

  function selectGame() {
    setSelectedGame(gameSelectInput.value);
    typeSelectInput.value = 'default';
    setSelectedType(null);
    modelSelectInput.value = 'default';
    setSelectedModel(null);
    skinSelectInput.value = 'default';
  }
  function selectType() {
    setSelectedType(typeSelectInput.value);
    modelSelectInput.value = 'default';
    setSelectedModel(null);
    skinSelectInput.value = 'default';
  }
  function selectModel() {
    setSelectedModel(modelSelectInput.value);
    skinSelectInput.value = 'default';
  }

  const gameList = Object.keys(gameListData);

  let typeList = [];
  let modelList = [];
  let skinList = [];

  if (gameList.includes(selectedGame)) {
    typeList = Object.keys(gameListData[selectedGame].skin_types);
  } else { typeList = []; }

  if (typeList.includes(selectedType)) {
    modelList = Object.keys(gameListData[selectedGame].skin_types[selectedType].entries);
  } else { modelList = []; }

  if (modelList.includes(selectedModel)) {
    skinList = Object.keys(gameListData[selectedGame]
      .skin_types[selectedType].entries[selectedModel].skins);
  } else { skinList = []; }

  if (isLoading) {
    <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <Logo />
      <div className="flex flex-nowrap">
        <VerticalAd1 />
        <div className="flex-shrink flex-grow lg:px-4">
          <section className="text-xs">
            <div className="flex flex-wrap mb-5">
              <div>
                <h3 className="section-title-sm">game</h3>
                <select id="game-select" className="input dark:input" onChange={selectGame}>
                  <option value="null">Game...</option>
                  {gameList.map((game, id) => (
                    <option id={id} key={game} value={game}>{gameListData[game].name}</option>
                  ))}
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="spaced-items-4 flex-wrap items-end mb-5">

              <div>
                <h3 className="section-title-sm">type</h3>
                <select id="type-select" className="input dark:input" onChange={selectType}>
                  <option value="null">Type...</option>
                  {typeList.map((type, id) => (
                    <option id={id} key={type} value={type}>{type}</option>
                  ))}
                </select>
              </div>

              <div>
                <h3 className="section-title-sm">model</h3>
                <select id="model-select" className="input dark:input" onChange={selectModel}>
                  <option value="null">Model...</option>
                  {modelList.map((model, id) => (
                    <option id={id} key={model} value={model}>
                      {gameListData[selectedGame].skin_types[selectedType].entries[model].name}
                    </option>
                  ))}
                </select>
              </div>

              <div>
                <h3 className="section-title-sm">variation</h3>
                <select id="skin-select" className="input dark:input">
                  <option value="null">Skin...</option>
                  {skinList.map((skin, id) => (
                    <option id={id} key={skin} value={skin}>
                      {gameListData[selectedGame]
                        .skin_types[selectedType].entries[selectedModel]
                        .skins[skin].name}
                    </option>
                  ))}
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

          </section>
        </div>

      </div>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Thank you for your patience! :)

Answer (score 1):

Ways to slim down this component off the top of my head:

1. Use a custom hook or multiple custom hooks.
   You could move your hooks and the functionality that relates to them into this custom hook and end up with something that looks like this:

```js
const { gameListData, selectedGame, selectedType, selectedModel, selectGame, selectType, selectModel } = useModelViewer();
```

This would involve wrapping all your hooks as well as your selectGame, selectType, and selectModel functions into the custom hook.

2. Split your JSX into multiple components.
   From what I see there are four clearly separate elements of your JSX. Your game selector, type selector, model selector, and skin selector can all be moved into their own small component.

This isn't an exhaustive list or your only options, but a couple of steps that would be good to follow for getting started.

P.S: Use React.useRef() instead of document.getElementById('game-select').